# How can I add items to a list when a checkbox is checked in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a list of checkbox and I want that when it's checked, the label or the value of the checkbox will be added in a list.

The fiddle below, when the checkbox is checked/unchecked, it adds 'on' to the list.

[Here's a sample fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vanduzled/xjpx60zd/)

```
$('.cb').click(function() {
  var cbVal = $("input[type='checkbox']").val();
  $('ul').append('<li>'+cbVal+'</li>')
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Up on clicking, you can iterate the checkboxes, see checked state and update the list.

```
$('.cb').click(function() {
$('ul').html("");
$(".cb").each(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
         $('ul').append('<li>'+$(this).val()+'</li>')
    }
});
});
```

Following is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xjpx60zd/2/).

Comment: I agree it works great but what would happen if there are like hundreds such checkboxes. You are re-creating the list every time you check/uncheck a checkbox.

Comment: Can it be saved in a local storage so that when checked and reloaded, it will be saved?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` inside event handler to be able to check what checkbook was selected, also it is better to use `change` event here.

```
$('.cb').change(function() {
  var cbVal = this.checked ? 'on ' : 'off ';
  cbVal += $('[for='+this.id+']').text ();
  $('ul').append('<li>'+cbVal+'</li>');
});
```

To be able to remove `li` from `ul` add id to it when appending `$('ul').append('<li id="item-' + this.id + '">' +cbVal+'</li>');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.cb').click(function () {
    var  szId=$(this).attr('id');
    var cbVal = $('label[for=' + szId + ']').text();
    $('ul').append('<li>' + cbVal + '</li>')
  });
});
```